# DBI: selectall_arrayref and columnnames

Tags: perl, dbi

When I fetch the data this way is it possible then to access the column names and the column types or do I need an explicit `prepare` to reach this?

```
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( ... ); 
my $select = "...";
my @arguments = ( ... );

my $ref = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( $select, {}, @arguments, );
```

Update:

With `prepare` I would do it this way:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $select );
$sth->execute( @arguments );
my $col_names = $sth->{NAME};
my $col_types = $sth->{TYPE};
my $ref = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
unshift @$ref, $col_names;
```

Comment: Why do you use `selectall_arrayref` and not `selectall_hashref`, if you want to get the column names as well? As for `column types`, I wonder what do you actually mean by that: the info returned by `column_info` method, or that related to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to use `prepare` to get a statement handle, as you describe in the second part of your question. If you use `selectall_hashref` or `selectall_arrayref`, you don't get a statement handle, and have to query the column type information yourself via `$dbh->column_info` ([docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#column_info)):

```
my $sth = $dbh->column_info('','',$table,$column);  # or $column='' for all
my $info = $sth->fetchall_arrayref({});
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($info);
```

(specifically, the COLUMN_NAME and TYPE_NAME attributes).

However, this introduces a race condition if the table changes schema between the two queries.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you may use `selectall_arrayref` with the `Slice` parameter to fetch all the columns into a hash ref, it needs no prepared statement and will return an array ref of the result set rows, with each rows columns the key's to a hash and the values are the column values. ie:

```
my $result = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( qq{
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition = value
}, { Slice => {} }) or die "Error: ".$dbh->errstr;

$result = [
[0] = { column1 => 'column1Value', column2 => 'column2Value', etc...},
[1] = { column1 => 'column1Value', column2 => 'column2Value', etc...},
];
```

Making it easy to iterate over results.. ie:

```
for my $row ( @$results ){
   print "$row->{column1Value}, $row->{column2Value}\n";
}
```

You can also specify which columns to extract but it's pretty useless due to the fact it's more efficient to do that in your SQL query syntax.

```
{ Slice => { column1Name => 1, column2Name => 1 } }
```

That would only return the values for column1Name and column2Name just like saying in your SQL:

```
SELECT column1Name, column2Name FROM table...
```